# Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

Actually, i am using jquery datatables in HMVC. when i write charector in serarch bar of datatable it gives me error like if i write 'foo' it will give me

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%foo%' OR uid LIKE '%foo%' OR pwd LIKE '%foo%' OR pooling LIKE '%foo%' OR ' at line 3

My Query:

```
 public function data_loc_table()

     {
       $this->load->helper('datatables');            
       $this->datatables->select('data_location_id,group_name,provider,driver,server,port,protocol,database,uid,pwd,pooling,min_pool_size,max_pool_size,conn_reset,conn_life_time,modified_time,status')

            ->unset_column('data_location_id')
            ->unset_column('status')
            ->add_column('Status','$1', 'get_connected_meters(status)')
            ->add_column('Actions', get_dloc_buttons('$1'), 'data_location_id')
            ->from('data_location');
            return ;
        }
```

Description:
Please help me find out why do I have this error?

Comment: What framework? Maybe you need to pass not string, but multiple strings or array to `->select`

Comment: I'm not sure while return is defined with nothing `return ;`

Comment: its codeigniter framework. Dear Rangith i am using datatables when i enter some charector in search bar of datatable then it gives me Error like i mention

Comment: when i enter 'foo' in search bar to search from datatable it gives me error like this:

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%foo%' OR uid LIKE '%foo%' OR pwd LIKE '%foo%' OR pooling LIKE '%foo%' OR ' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with

```
'$1'
```

We can't use php variables in single quotes(' '), so try replacing these single quotes with double quotes(" ")

Replace

> '$1'

with

> "$1"

Comment: Sorry, DWX but its not working!

Comment: Alright, its giving error just before "uid" in the "$this->datatables->select('data_location_id,group_name,provider,driver,server,port,protocol,database,uid,pwd,pooling,min_pool_size,max_pool_size,conn_reset,conn_life_time,modified_time,status')"

You can't use predefined keywords or functions like "database", as  you have used just before uid.
So try removing "database" from  $this->datatables->select();

Comment: Thanks alot!! DWX You are such a fabulous!! -:)